# Weird reputation log

Tags: bug, reputation

One of the "recurring troublemakers" had made a recent appearance, but with reputation of 107 points, something was off, there were no posts and no edits. When I checked the reputation log on their account the following showed up.

[image]

There are no reputation changes, and yet, the reputation persists. How can this thing happen?

Answer (score 4):

This probably should be confirmed by a diamond-wearing user (or by somebody who can find the deleted post causing this), but I think this is due to the fact that reputation changes remain in place after deletion of a post if the post the post has score at least +3 and it has been visible at least for 60 days. See: [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237)

---

You may notice this discussion on meta.math.SE: [Reputation tab seems to be insensitive to deletion of upvoted answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24905). A user mentioned there that the reputation has not been deducted after deleting an answer. If you look at this users reputation tab and find the date in question, you can see this:

[image: screenshot of the reputation tab]

So the displayed behavior is consistent with what you describe in your post.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I totally forgot about that.

Comment: The possible suspect post was deleted on May 8. The tally is 4 upvotes, 4 downvotes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and the information about the votes @ToddTrimble. Since the post had score zero at the time of deletion, it is most likely not the post which caused this. So I have removed that part of my post.

Comment: The question I linked in my post was deleted in the meantime = however, the information can be found, for example, here: [Does reputation change if an answer gets deleted due to deletion of original post by vote(s)?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31176)